# Webservice testing without SoapUI

Tags: web-services, wsdl, soapui

I am new to the Webservice Testing. Someone Can please answer the below Questions-
1) How to do WebServisce Testing without any SOAP UI.
2) If URL is not working but we have WSDL file, can Webservice testing be done?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use soapUI? The open source version is free and has plenty of features. But, if you really must use something else there's [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or you can go down to the code level in the programming language of your choice, such as [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) for Java.

Then, if you have a WSDL but it's not active, there are plenty of mocking tools (in soapUI and Postman), frameworks, and services ([WireMock](http://wiremock.org/) or [Mockable](https://www.mockable.io/)) available.

Comment: Thanks...i'll go for Java coding